# Error vsftpd ftp user could download file in any folder of linux server. How to restrict to only home/default folder?

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

In CentOS Linux server we have ftp software vsftpd, with this config in /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES

chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list
userlist_deny=NO
tcp_wrappers=YES
use_localtime=YES
ftpd_banner="Welcome to FTP Server name_of_app"
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=10000
pasv_max_port=20000
local_root=/home/ftp_user
```

The problem is that ftp_user could access any file/ folder in linux server via ftp://server_ip, for e.g ftp_user could download /etc/passwd file. How to restrict ftp_user to only access /home/ftp_user folder?